# Variables by reference or by value? Java

Tags: java, sockets, pass-by-reference

I have a socket which is currently connected.

```
Socket s; //Connected socket
```

If I use:

```
 Socket d = s;
```

Will socket `d` be the same, connected socket? It depends if java is assigning by value or reference, in this case I would like it to assign by reference. I'm not sure what it's going to do exactly so I'm asking here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will socket `d` be the same, connected socket?

Yes

> It depends if java is assigning by value or reference

Java is *entirely* pass-by/assign-by **value**. The value being assigned here is a reference to the object. Think of it as an `int` that tells us what slot in memory the object is in.

Continuing the `int` analogy:

```
int a;
int b;

a = 5;
b = a;
a = 6;
```

What's `b`'s value? `5`, of course, the later assignment of `6` to `a` has nothing to do with the value stored in `b`.

And so similarly:

```
Socket d;
Socket s;

d = /* ... create and connect a socket... */;
s = d;
d = null;
```

What's the value of `s`? Right! It's the reference to the connected socket object. The value in `s` (a reference to the socket) is completely unaffected by your assigning a different value to `d`.

Now, of course, when `d` and `s` are pointing (referring) to the same object, naturally any time that object changes, you can see the change via `d` or `s`. All that `d` and `s` do is tell us where the object is, they don't *contain* the object at all. They point to the memory that contains the object.

Once you grasp that object *references* are primitives just like `int`s and have exactly the same behavior, understanding Java code gets a *lot* easier.

Comment: The other answers were also great. Thanks for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 6):

Will socket d be the same, connected socket? Yes

---

In `Java` objects are created in a special area in the memory called “**Heap**”.
So `s` and `d` are only the pointers ( or references ) for the Socket object you created 
in the Heap area.

[image]

Comment: I'd upvote this answer for the diagram, except...I'd already upvoted it earlier for the clear simplicity of your text. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say s is a reference to a Socket, d will be a copy of the reference to the Socket.

If you do "d = null", it won't affect s.

Comment: and if you do s = null, will it affect d?

Comment: No, s an d are both copies of a reference to the same object, there is no one original copy.

Answer (score 0):

when you initialize socket d

you are creating a reference pointer d which are trying to pointing a object.

if Socket s = socketobject(), s is also a reference pointer pointing to a socketobject.

so if you assign d = s, which means the reference pointer of d is same as the reference pointer of s, which points to the socketobject as well.

So your answer should be YES

Answer (score 0):

`Java` references are different from `C++` references. In `C++`, once a reference is created, it cannot be later made to reference another object; it cannot be reseated. In `Java`it can be.

So after:

```
Socket d = s;
```

you can make d (or s) point to some other `Socket` object, but even then s (or d) would still point to the original `Socket`.